# opening webpage with powershell in IE hangs

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

I try to open a webpage with Powershell code in order to print the page with PDFCreator. It hangs when I try to run it; probably when opening internet explorer.

```
$ie = new-object -com internetexplorer.application 
if ($showWindow) {
    $ie.Visible = $true
} else {
    $ie.Visible = $false
}
$ie.navigate($WebSiteURL)
```

Why does this hang and how can I fix this?

Comment: I could not add the full code since I get the message that my post is mostly code...

Comment: There is a reason for that message. You're supposed to explain your problem and what you've tried and what happened. Don't just dump your code here and hope that someone magically fixes it for you. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: I cannot add a more info since it is a very simple program written to print the contents of a webpage with PDFCreator. There is no error message from Powershell either. I have diminished the code and sow that the webpage is opened, so the problem must be further on when I open PDFCreator. I would  revise the question but cannot edit it anymore..

Comment: I debugged furtheron. The problem is the            $ie.execWB(6,1)  or            $ie.execWB(6,2)  command waiting for me to press the "print" button. What are the right arguments for IE under W10?

Comment: When I use execWB(6,3) to print without promp I receive:Trying to revoke a drop target that has not been registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040100 (DRAGDROP_E_NOTREGISTERED))
At D:\DATA-MEDION\soft_ontwikkeling\powershell\WebpageToPdf.ps1:53 char:13
+             $ie.execWB(6,3) #print zonder prompt
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
   I waited 15 sec befor the ie.execWB and the page was present in IE.

Comment: I try to check your sample code and find that the code you posted in original post has nothing to do with your actual issue. I suggest you to provide a proper sample code which can reproduce the issue on our side. It can be helpful to understand the issue in better way. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Indeed problem was furtheron… as in previous comment

Comment: You need to post a proper code example which we can try to test on our side to check the issue.  execWB(6,3) will not give any information about the cause for the issue. I suggest you to modify your original post with reproducible example. We will try to test that code.